# How can I get access to a video card frame buffer in a WPF app?

Tags: wpf, video, graphics, hardware, framebuffer

I'm trying to write a (very minimal) WPF app which will look at a video card frame buffer and do some image analysis on the data.

I'm a complete noob when it comes to this kind of stuff, and I've tried going down a couple roads before posting, but I'm completely lost on what will actually get me what I want.

This is going to be used to grab frames while playing a full screen video game (starcraft 2), but it should be able to grab frames for the duration of the app (when simply looking at the Windows desktop...).

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but after some googling I found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/csharpgeneral/thread/33297e25-d8f7-482c-9de5-ececeb297bb1) think. I don't know if it works with Directx / OpenGL, but it's worth trying.

Comment: Worked well actually.  Thanks.